# How do I sanitize string fields containing HTML at model level?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, sanitization

I have an app using Spring, JPA (Hibernate) and the Java validation framework (Hibernate Validator). I would like to be able to annotate fields in our domain model that are allowed to contain HTML and have them automatically sanitized at commit time. Anyone know a clever way to do this?

I have tried using the validation framework but this does not support modifying the value of the field at validation time. I could hack things to get something working but am hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with JPA Entity Listeners annotations:

> @PreUpdate
>
> @PrePersist

Anothers solution would be to do it in the own setter.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just doing the cleaning in the setter. Not as neat as doing it declaratively with an annotation but real simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@SafeHtml` tag to do just that. You will need to include `Jsoup` library as a dependency.

Heres some more info: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-validator-constraints